# Existence of a convergent sub-series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can anyone give me a hint for proving the following?

Let $(a_k)$ be a **positive** real sequence so that $a_k \to 0$. Prove that there exists a subsequence $(a_{s_k})$ such that the series 
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 3^k a_{s_k}$ converges.

Comment: Let $s_k = \min\{s \in \mathbb{N} \vert \,  \vert a_s \vert < 3^{-k-1}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The intuition here is that, even though the sequence $(a_k)$ might be decreasing *very* slowly, since it goes to zero, you can always find a term that is as small as you want by picking the index $k$ to be sufficiently large. For instance, you can find some indices $s_1,s_2,\dots$ so that $a_{s_1} < 3^{-1}$, $a_{s_2}< 3^{-2}$, and in general $a_{s_k}<3^{-k}$. If you chose the subsequence $(a_{s_k})$, then there would be an inequality $3^ka_{s_k} < 3^k\cdot 3^{-k}=1$. This is not enough to guarantee that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^k a_{s_k}$ converges, since all we know is that the terms are less than $1$; but we can choose larger indices to make the terms of the subsequence even smaller.

Do you see what to do now?